# WCF REST service not returning DataContract object

Tags: wcf, datacontract

I have a simple WCF service defined by the following ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IInventoryService
{
  [OperationContract]      
  Item GetItemFromBarcode(string barcode);

  [OperationContract]
  string Test(string testString);
}
```

With Item defined like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
  [DataMember]
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }

  <Snip>
}
```

And the actual service implemented thusly:

```
public class InventoryService : IInventoryService
{
  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Barcode/{barcode}/Item", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  public Item GetItemFromBarcode(string barcode)
  {
     var item = (from b in repository.Query<ItemBarcode>()
             where b.BarcodeData == barcode
             select b.Item).FirstOrDefault();
     return item;

  }

  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Test/{testString}",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
  public string Test(string testString)
  {
     return testString;
  }
}
```

With the following in the app.config for the program hosting the service:

```
<system.serviceModel>      
  <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
     <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RESTFriendly">
           <webHttp />
        </behavior>
     </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
     <service name="InventoryService">            
        <endpoint address="/Inventory" behaviorConfiguration="RESTFriendly" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IInventoryService"/>
        <host>
           <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>
           </baseAddresses>
        </host>
     </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Now that the code dump is out of the way, the issue: I can invoke the `Test` method just fine with curl or Fiddler, it returns a serialized string. However, invoking the method that returns an object returns nothing. Curl spits back `curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer` and Fiddler responds `ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.`

From what I read, this should Just Work (tm). Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Is it possible that an exception is occurring in GetItemFromBarcode? Maybe modifying to just return an Item created inline to make sure your WCF config is correct, because exception handling in WCF REST is a little obfuscated. Alternatively, what is the rest of the Item class, maybe it is a serialization problem? You could also turn on WCF tracing.

Comment: @James Webster, an exception isn't being thrown that I can find (I told Visual Studio to break on all exceptions). Actually, I think I just figured out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems you can't have `DataMember` of an interface type, like the `IList<ItemBarcode>`. There go my hopes of using my NHibernate model objects as DTOs.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I suppose because the deserializer doesn't know which concrete type to create. WCF could make an assumption about which implementation to use; but this would probably break a number of use cases. Hence WCF requires concrete types (in most cases). Using NHibernate objects as DTOs would be problematic in general I think. Maybe you should consider a separate DTO layer and use AutoMapper to simplify mapping in both directions (maybe even code-gen the DTOs using T4?)